# Returning Customers in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, woocommerce, e-commerce

On a WooCommerce powered shop site I would like to know for a certain product how often it has been **reordered** by a returning customer. To ask the same from the customer perspective: How many customers are there for a certain product that have ordered this product **more than once**?

I need this data to decide whether it would make sense to switch to a subscription based model for this product. Here it is a certain coffee, that is, if it's reordered by the same customers very often, then there's certainly some interesting by customers for coffee subscriptions.

Am I correct that Google Analytics only has a conception of a **returning visitor** but not of a **returning customer** (someone ordering again)?

Comment: You could use segmentation, i.e. "users where nr. of transactions > 1". However this depends very much on how accurate GA recongnizes recurring visitors (not very). If users need to log in to order you could implement userID tracking, where the identifier for the user is set by your backend system after login, which works across devices and is more reliable than a cookie-based approach (additional TOS apply, especially regarding privacy).

Comment: @EikePierstorff You'd also have an issue with people who cancelled an order, since they'd still have more than one transaction.

Comment: Yes. That, too, could be solved via segmentation (provided you register canceled orders in the first place within GA). All in all GA data is probably not the best for this purpose, it might be better to run a query in the fullfillment system or CRM.